# iterate over multiple tables in HANA

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, hana

I have 4-5 tables in my SAP HANA database. My requirement is to list all tables and iterate over each table and store each table data to individual csv files.

I want to perform these activity using python. I am using the **hdbcli** library for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `collect()` method of the [hana-ml dataframe](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#) and subsequently export using Pandas `to_csv(..)` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
connectionContext.table('my_table').collect().to_csv(..)
```

For this approach, you need to use [hana-ml](https://pypi.org/project/hana-ml/) instead of [hdbcli](https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/).